# Will this architecture be effective for a dashboard that is cross platform/browser compatible?

Tags: mobile, architecture, dashboard

I am researching architecture for a dashboard for my company to eliminate the clunky reporting UI we have now that has a treeview menu and uses the SQL Reporting Services Report Viewer control.

I am considering using ASP.NET MVC 4 server side and Telerik Kendo UI on the client side for the data tables, charts, and graphs. For data access, I would use ADOMD.NET to retrieve data from the SSAS cube.

Reasons for this is I am interested in something that is lightweight, fast, and that runs equally well on Android tablets, iPad's, in Firefox, Safari, and IE 9, iPhone's, Android phones, etc.

Will this be an effective architecture for a lightweight, cross platform compatible corporate dashboard? For a MSFT environment, are there better alternatives that meet my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a very similar project with ASP.NET MVC3/4 and Telerik Kendo UI.

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349071/best-option-to-retrieve-anaylysis-services-ssas-cube-data-dynamically-in-asp-n) concerning the easiest way of doing this, using a third-party Entity Framework provider. Technically this would mean that all you have to do is serializing the data source obtained from [SSAS Entity Framework Provider](http://www.agiledesignllc.com/products) to JSON then giving it to a Kendo UI control and you're in business.